# Why am I getting a Forbidden (403) CSRF cookie not set error when trying to login after deploying my Django project?

Tags: django, authentication, cookies, deployment, csrf

Django project works locally, but when I deployed it and tried to login I got Forbidden (403)  CSRF cookie not set.

My settings.py have this code

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware','django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
# template stuff
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': PROJECT_TEMPLATES,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Internationalization
USE_I18N = False
SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = None
#SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'new_session_id'
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'new_csrf_token'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False
#CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True 
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS =["http://34.118.121.194:8000","https://34.118.121.194:8000",'http://34.118.121.194:8000/','https://34.118.121.194:8000/']
#SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 7200
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
#SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'localhost:8000'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

I have the csrf tag in my form.
I tried mutliple things, but nothing helped.
I also inspected it and noticed that the set-cookie is present in the login get request, but not in the post. The cookie in the get request looks like this:

```
Set-Cookie:
new_session_id=7hdqxannws6eakk1ayc8at3dldustjrj; expires=Mon, 12 Jun 2023 09:28:14 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=None
```

I have deployed it with google cloud, not sure whether it can affect it or not.
The connection to the site is not secure also.
Please give suggetions what the problem might be.